# Magento <IfVersion', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Tags: .htaccess, magento, wamp, host, internal

I'm trying to setup a WAMP Server with magento however whenever I try and access the magento folder in local host I get an Internal error.

When I read the Apache error message it reads " C:/wamp64/www/Magento2/.htaccess: Invalid command '

I have attempted to use Apache Module mod_version however i got very confused in understanding what to actually do.

Any help and advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

enable mod_version in apache modules

In apache version 2.4.9, mod_version module is named as "version_module" in WAMP. I enabled it and magento worked as charm.

Answer (score 4):

The solution provided by [asad abbas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8887240/asad-abbas) works for me for apache version 2.4.39 i.e. enable mode_version.so in httpd.conf file.

After I enabled it, the line looks something like this:

```
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
```

And its screenshot is:

[image: Screen shot after enabling the module]

Answer (score 0):

Go to apache(httpd.conf) and uncomment this module
**LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so**